# Add field filters to spotify query

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify, urlencode

I am trying to use the Spotify API to search for a track. In the documentation it states you can narrow your search using field filters (such as album, artist, track). I don't know how to insert these field filters into my request however. I am trying to search for a track using both the track name and artist name to ensure accurate results.

I have tried to alter my params in my request to include these filters:

```
params = {
  "q": urllib.parse.quote("track:"+track_name+" "+"artist:"+artist_name)
}
```

I have tried this both with url encoding and without to no success. I believe the result of the above code is to create a long query of `track:*track_name* artist:*artist_name*` where the filters are part of the query rather than filtering. I am looking for a solution to allow me to properly use the field filters in my query.

Edit:
spotify api on searching for an item: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search

Comment: it would be helpful to include: 1) links to documentation you're working off of, 2) output of your current code, and 3) what you expecting as output.

Comment: @AdamSmooch The output is a large json object that wouldn't make much sense to post here. When I insert a real track name and a real artist name into my current code the results are not as accurate as just making the query the track name. Added link to documentation.

Comment: @mm3psych0sis you don't have to paste an entire object. You can just include the important part/excerpts.